# Object.prototype break Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron version: 4.0.1, Operating system: MacOS Mojave

Declare and use any Object prototypes will cause the following error in Electron.

```
Object.prototype.LOG=console.log;
new Object().LOG(this);  //<-- menu.groupsMap[id].find is not a function
```

Some closed issues found in their Git but no clue how to fix it.

- Object.prototype.name gets clobbered https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6966
- menu.getMenuItemById is not a function https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11405

Any suggestion for this? Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Object.prototype break Electron]

Comment: I ran in to this same exact problem.  Did you find a solution?